# Finding the eigenvalues and the basis for each eigenspace of the matrix ...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

They give me the matrix \begin{bmatrix}3 \ -2 \\ \ 3 \  \ \ \ \ \  1\end{bmatrix}

Until now I have done

Det(λI - A) = Det of\begin{bmatrix}λ -3 \ \ \ \ \ \ 2 \\ \ -3 \  \ \ \ \ \  λ-1\end{bmatrix}

I get that the eigen values are:

λ = 2+$i\sqrt{5}$

λ = 2-$i\sqrt{5}$

And now I am stuck when I try to find the basis for each of the eigenspaces. I know I have to do 
:

I$λ_1 - A$ and find the basis for the resulting matrix but the $i$ in the eigenvalues are giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, the eigenvalues of  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ are $\lambda_1 = 2 - \sqrt{5} i$ and $\lambda_2 = 2 + \sqrt{5} i$. And so, we can find the corresponding eigenvectors by solving $(A - \lambda I) = \mathbf{0}$. For example, for $\lambda_1$,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 - (2 - \sqrt{5}i) & -2 \\ 3 & 1 - (2 - \sqrt{5}i) \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$

As you have probably found out, doing row reduction on the above is difficult. However, there's a trick: $(A - \lambda I) = \mathbf{0}$ must have *non-trivial* solution, which implies that the matrix $(A - \lambda I)$ is *not* invertible. That means, $(A - \lambda I)$'s rows are *linearly dependent*. What does that mean? We can pick *one* of the equivalent linear equations below, because they both describe the *same* relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$:

$$3 - (2 - \sqrt{5}i) x_1 - 2 x_2 = 0$$

$$3 x_1 + 1 - (2 - \sqrt{5}i) x_2 = 0$$

Suppose we pick the first one:

$$3 - (2 - \sqrt{5}i) x_1 - 2 x_2 = 0$$

$$1 + \sqrt{5}i x_1 - 2 x_2 = 0$$

$$x_1 = \frac{2 x_2}{1 + \sqrt{5}i}$$

therefore, the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_1$ have the following form:

$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2 x_2}{1 + \sqrt{5}i} \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = x_2 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{5}i} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

And so, the basis for eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is $\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{5}i} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg\}$. You can use the same technique to find the basis for eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_2$.

Answer (score 0):

We look for $X=(u,v)$ such that

$$3u-2v=\lambda u=(2+ i\sqrt 5)u$$

or

$$v=\frac{1- i\sqrt 5}{2}u$$

hence, the eigenvectors are

$X_1=(2,1-i\sqrt 5)$ for $2+i\sqrt 5$

and

$X_2=(2,1+i\sqrt 5)$ for $2-i\sqrt 5$.